# RadDataGrid Row Count

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, rad-controls

I was trying to add multiple datagrid .Counts together But didn't quite work. It works on linq Pad but didn't work in visual studio.
I have 4 datagrids: datagrid1, datagrid2, datagrid3, datagrid4 
I am Currently Using RadDataGrids

```
Var Total = datagrid1.Count() + datagrid2.Count() + datagrid3.Count() + datagrid4.Count()
```

That code didn't quite work, Not sure what's happening

Comment: What type are your `datagrids`?

Comment: RadDataGrids  are my datagrids

Comment: `datagrid1,2,3,4` are `DataGrid` or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I looke at the [right place](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-8-xaml/raddatagrid-gettingstarted.html), it looks like you could use `ItemsSource` property

something like

```
var total = dataGrid1.ItemsSource.Count() + dataGrid2.ItemsSource.Count() + dataGrid3.ItemsSource.Count();
```

Comment: Can also use `Items` Instead `ItemsSource`. Not?

Comment: This is not DataGrid, but RadDataGrid. Seems that RadDataGrid doesn't have an Items property.